# Fill PDF Form with iTextSharp - add image, and keep editable

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am attempting to use iTextSharp to manipulate a fillable, pdf form template.  A good example of a source form would by the IRS's fillable W4 (though, I will be authoring my own forms in the real solution): http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf

I need to:

1. Fill in some form inputs, but not all
2. Add some custom metadata to the pdf
3. Add a barcode image to the pdf
4. Have the generated form still be fillable in Acrobat Reader

I have already overcome what appears to be a common problem where the PdfStamper must created to Append to the pdf - this works fine when filling in form inputs and adding the metadata.  However, if I add an image to the PDF, it results in the very disappointing message of

> This document enabled extended features in Adobe Reader.  The document
>   has been changed since it was created and use of extended features is
>   no longer available.  etc...

Because of this, the form can no longer be edited in Acrobat Reader.

Here is a high level example of the code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(templateFile);                                  
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create), '\0', true))
{
    // fill in some fields
    AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
    form.SetField("Field1", "My Value");
    form.SetField("Field2", "Another Value");

    // add some metadata
    Dictionary<String, String> info = reader.Info;                
    info.Add("SourceID", "1234567890");
    stamper.MoreInfo = info;

    // add a barcode image
    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
    Barcode39 code39ext = new Barcode39();
    code39ext.Code = "1234567890";
    code39ext.StartStopText = false;
    code39ext.Extended = true;
    iTextSharp.text.Image barcode = code39ext.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
    barcode.ScalePercent(100);
    barcode.SetAbsolutePosition(50, 500);
    cb.AddImage(barcode)

    stamper.Close();
}
```

Primary Question: As mentioned, the field completion and metadata parts work fine.  However, adding the barcode image breaks the "extended features" of the pdf.  Is there a way that I can add the barcode image that doesn't break the "extended features"?

Comment: You add the bar code to the regular PDF content. That usually breaks a signature. You might try some annotation for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide an answer for others, @mkl is correct.  By modifying the "content" of the pdf, the signature is broken.  However, it is possible to fill the form, add metadata, and add the barcode to a fillable PDF, as long as the "extended reader features" are not enabled.  Since we are authoring our own forms, this was a valid solution for us.